# Error in updating initramfs in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, boot, initramfs

I was installing a Linux kernel(version 5.6.0-rc+) on Ubuntu. For that I compiled the kernel as follow:

- `sudo make ARCH=x86_64 x86_64_defconfig`
- `sudo make -j256`
- `sudo make modules`
- `sudo make modules_install`
- `sudo make install`

Output of the last command is as follow:

```
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 5.6.0-rc6+ arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
    System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 5.6.0-rc6+ /boot/vmlinuz-5.6.0-rc6+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 5.6.0-rc6+ /boot/vmlinuz-5.6.0-rc6+
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.6.0-rc6+
find: ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_M0HzSl/lib/modules/5.6.0-rc6+/kernel’: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 5.6.0-rc6+ /boot/vmlinuz-5.6.0-rc6+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 5.6.0-rc6+ /boot/vmlinuz-5.6.0-rc6+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 5.6.0-rc6+ /boot/vmlinuz-5.6.0-rc6+
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0+
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0+
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.6.0-rc6+
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.6.0-rc6+
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-81-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-81-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-72-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-72-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

Now, when I boot the newly installed kernel it says that `Initramfs unpacking failed!` and lands into `initramfs` prompt. Upon `exit` from the `initramfs` prompt it suggests the issue to be the modules not being loaded. Also, note the output I attached above, the `update-initramfs` command was not successful. So, I think that the reason the kernel not booting up is the failure of `update-initramfs`. Not sure though.

So can anyone please suggest what could be the reason behind the failure of `update-initramfs`?

Thanks.

Comment: You also need to use `sudo` when you install modules: `sudo make modules_install`. Also, you don't need `make modules` if you previously did `make`.

Comment: Actually I executed all the commands with `sudo`. Will update the question.

Comment: Only `make modules_install` and `make install` require `sudo`. Maybe that's not the problem, but it's definitely not a good idea to use `sudo` when compiling.

Comment: Yeah that's true. But I used `sudo` as I was working in a directory where normally I don't have write permission.

Comment: I just updated `update-initramfs`. Now there is no error with `sudo make install`. But kernel still does not boot.

Comment: You're in the wrong place. StackOverflow is for programming questions only. You should ask this in https://SuperUser.com